# Why does this RSpec pass in one file and fail in another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

My Rails project's 'spec' folder contains the following:

1) a 'controllers' subfolder with:
 a) a 'pages_controller' spec file (with corresponding "describe PagesController do" statement):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
  end

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", content: @base_title+"Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title", content: @base_title+"Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title", content: @base_title+"About")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'help'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'help'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should contain the right title" do
      get 'help'
      response.should have_selector("title", content: @base_title+"Help")
    end
  end

end
```

b) a 'users_controller' spec file (with corresponding "describe UsersController do" statement):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET '/new'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get 'new'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'new'
      response.should have_selector("title", content: "Sign up")
    end

  end

end
```

2) a 'requests' subfolder with the following 'layout_links' spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector('title', content: 'Home')
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/content'" do
    get '/contact'
    response.should have_selector('title', content: 'Contact')
  end

  it "should have an About page at '/about'" do
    get '/about'
    response.should have_selector('title', content: 'About')
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
    get '/help'
    response.should have_selector('title', content: 'Help')
  end

  it "should have a signup page at '/signup'" do
    get '/signup'
    response.should have_selector("title", content: "Sign up")
  end

end
```

I initially added the following code to my "users_controller" file:

```
it "should have a signup page at '/signup'" do
  get '/signup'
  response.should have_selector("title", content: "Sign up")
end
```

The test failed when I ran it, but when I added it to the 'layout_links' spec file, it passed.  This tells me that I am missing some fundamental aspect of RSpec and/or integration testing.  Am happy to re-word this question to make it more universal, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hunch is correct, there is some convention over configuration going on here.

Controller tests will work off the controller specified. So your `PagesController` test will work off...well, the `PagesController`. So the `get 'home'` line will try to get the `home` action in your `Pages` controller, the `Pages` controller is assume for all of those tests. Unless your `Pages` controller has a `signup` action it will error.

The `requests` type tests are for integration tests and don't assume a controller.